# SilverStripe move default SiteTree CMS fields to new tab

Tags: silverstripe

In a default SS3 setup, the CMS fields are placed in tab `Root.Main`. However, I wish to create two new tabs `Main Content` and `Form` so that the default CMS fields will be in `Root.Main.MainContent`.

I took a look at `SiteTree.php` to see how the fields are placed into the tab. It seems quite difficult to get between there.

Q: How to move default cms fields from `Root.Main` into `Root.Main.MainContent`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 3.3.2, the default fields are automatically placed into a tab named `Main Content`.  This `Main Content` tab is actually the `Root.Main` tab referenced in code. If the `Main Content` tab is the only tab then it is hidden since there is not much use to having only one tab.

To do you what you want simply create your fields and then add them to the new `Form` tab:

```
$myNewField = new LiteralField("Lipsum","Ipsum dolor sit amet enim.");
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Form', $myNewField );
```

Answer (score 2):

AlphaCactus' answer should be what you want, but if you want to create a third level tabset, you can use code similar to:

```
$fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', Tabset::create('MainTabset',
    Tab::create('MainContent',
        TextField::create('Field1'),
        TextField::create('Field2')
    ),
    Tab::create('Form',
        TextField::create('Field3'),
        TextField::create('Field4')
    )
));
```

Comment: I had thought about including this in my answer, but that kind of nesting gets really complicated visually so you really gotta want it. From my testing, to add additional fields to those tabs, if not done at construction time or with stored references to nested tabs, gets kinda deep: `$fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main.MainTabset.Form', ... )`.  You can also add a tab directly to `Root.Main` so you can reference it by `Root.Main.FormTab`, but it doesn't provide any useful visual styling (at least in 3.3.2) over adding fields directly to the `Root.Main` tab so I don't recommend it.

Comment: @AlphaCactus Three levels of tabs gets a bit out of control. I wasn't aware that you could just add them using the first param in the addFieldsToTab function